# Component of roasted malt that lowers pH

Tags: mash, mash-ph, specialty-malt, ph

Roasted and kilned malts are often used to lower the pH of the mash. Which chemicals are created by the roasting process that have such a low pH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the [Brau Kaiser](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Mash_pH_control), it's acidic melanoidins. [Melanoidins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanoidin) are composed of sugars and amino acids, and are created through the Maillard reaction.

Comment: Hmm, after some searching, I found that it could also be some acetic acid in the malt, but acidic melanoidins seems the most likely candidate. Too bad I can't find any information about what acidic melanoidins are made of